# LINQ Select Based on Another Select

Tags: c#, linq

I always find myself stuck on LINQ in the same place.  I simply cannot make LINQ techniques stick in my head.

```
var groupIds = context.Set<UserControl>().Where(x => x.SystemUserId == System.Convert.ToInt32(userId)).Select(x => x.SystemGroupId);
{
    var userGroups = context.Set<Group>().Where(g => g.GroupId)
    {
        groups.AddRange(userGroups.Select(sysGroup => new ToolUserGroup(sysGroup.GroupName, sysGroup.GroupId.ToString())));
    }
}
```

I'm trying to select a list of `Group` objects based on the `GroupId` property of the list selected in the first list of `UserControl` ids.  I simply cannot figure out the syntax.

I'm not even sure this is easier that just writing the SQL by hand ... LINQ always appear to me to be so much more complex and abstract than just writing SQL.

Comment: What was your question again?

Comment: It's hard to understand exactly what you're trying to do. It would really help if you'd show your models, sample input data and expected output data.

Comment: Just a remark. If you are having difficulties with LINQ, maybe you should try to avoid method syntax and use query syntax ( see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397676.aspx ). Although both should be arbitrary, i think the query syntax is easier to read for somebody with SQL background

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming, you are trying to select a List based on a List of Items.

```
var groupIds = context.Set<UserControl>()
                  .Where(x => x.SystemUserId ==System.Convert.ToInt32(userId))
                  .Select(x => x.SystemGroupId);
                  .ToList();

var userGroups = context.Set<Group()
                        .Where(g=>groupIds.Contains(g.GroupId)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that

```
    class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class SubItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ForeignKey { get; set; }
    public string SubName { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sub = new List<SubItem>();
        var item = new List<Item>();

        sub.Where(s => item.Select(i => i.Id).Contains(s.ForeignKey)).ToList();
    }
}
```